# Get the values for multiples forms with just one button

Tags: angular, forms

I'm trying to get the result for multiples forms at same time...
Currently, I have a structure to get the result one by one but I need to send the result of all of them...

My html code:

```js
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" #f="ngForm" *ngFor="let x of selectedValue; index as i">
                    <mat-card > 
                        <mat-card-title class="title-card">
                            <span>{{x.name}}</span>
                        </mat-card-title>
                        <mat-card-content *ngFor="let param of x.modelParameter; index as i">
                            <div class="param-title">
                                <span><b>{{param.name}}</b></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="set-slider" *ngIf="param.type === 'continuous'"> 
                                <label class="gridSizeValue"><b>{{param.values_arr[0]}}</b></label>
                                <mat-slider #gridsize (change)="updateSetting($event)" class="slider" thumbLabel
                                    tickInterval="1" [displayWith]="formatLabel" min="{{param.values_arr[0]}}"
                                    max="{{param.values_arr[1]}}" aria-label="units" class="form-control" ngModel name="{{param.name}}">
                                </mat-slider>
                                <label class="gridSizeValue"><b>{{param.values_arr[1]}}</b></label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="set-categorical" *ngIf="param.type === 'categorical'">
                                <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                                    <mat-select 
                                    class="form-control"
                                    ngModel name="option">
                                        <mat-option *ngFor="let op of param.values_arr" [value]="op">
                                            {{op}}
                                        </mat-option>
                                    </mat-select>
                                </mat-form-field>
                            </div> 
                        </mat-card-content>
                    </mat-card>
                    <button mat-raised-button type="submit" class="save-button">Send Models</button>
                </form>
```

I was trying to put the button outside method but it does not work, and also I was trying to get the value by ngModel but it does not works neither.

Do you have any suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you has a template reference variable in a loop, when you use this variable is "scoped" to each iteration.

You can use ViewChildren to get all elements with the same "template reference Variable"

```
  @ViewChildren('f') forms:QueryList<NgForm>
```

A button type submit outside the loop can call to a function (you can call submit or in another way)

```
   <button (click)="submit()">
```

You function submit

```
submit()
{
   const isInvalid=this.forms.map(x=>x.valid).find(x=>!x)
   //isInvalid is "undefined" if all are valid
   //          is true if one of the forms is invalid

   if (!isInvalid)
   {
       this.forms.forEach(x=>{
         console.log(x.value)
     })
   }
}
```

Now we get the forms the question is: how you can create your data?

```
//in array
submit()
{
   ...
   const data=this.forms.map(x=>x.value)    

}
//in an object
submit()
{
   ...
   const obj:any={}
   this.forms.forEach((x,i)=>{
      obj['form'+i]=x.value
   })
}

//if the "name" of the controls are all differents
//using spread operator
submit()
{
   ...
   let obj:any={}
   this.forms.forEach((x,i)=>{
      obj={...obj,...x.value}
   })
}
```

BTW perhafs you want to take a look to use [[(ngModel)]](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel) using an array or [ReactiveForms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms)

Comment: Hi Eliseo, thank you for you answer, I have a question, how did you connect the value with HTML? 
Do you mean that ```<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" #f="ngForm"> ``` and the ```@ViewChildren('f') forms:QueryList<NgForm>``` are gonna be connected?

Comment: "how did you connect the value with HTML?" Really it's not in this way. When we use a template reference variable is like you declare a variable in .ts (well, we need use ViewChild -if is an unique- or ViewChildren to access this variable -that is "collected" in a [QueryList](https://angular.io/api/core/QueryList)). It's all the "magic". Remember Angular relates (make a binding) variables in .ts with the .html -ngModel or ReactiveForms makes a two-way-binding-

Comment: Yes, I got it man, when you put that, I was looking how it works and I could finish haha, thank you Eliseo!